# activemq-cpp pull consumer receive remote address

Tags: activemq-cpp

I have 2 activeMQ brokers with queues and I would like to be able to log incoming ActiveMQ message broker remote address.

After I perform pull consumer receive:
`pull_consumer->receive(1000);`

and after message arrives I do this:
`ActiveMQConnection *amqconn = dynamic_cast<ActiveMQConnection*>(connection);`

then try getting remote adress:
`amqconn->getTransport().getRemoteAddress().c_str()` but its always empty

I checked for `getTransport().isClosed()` and `getTransport().isConnected()` and they are not closed and connected

Or is there another way to retrieve this connection information ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the client has a bug that prevents that value getting filled in, or that bit was never implemented in the first place.  The ActiveMQ C++ client is no longer being maintained so you aren't likely to receive much if any real answer or support on that.  My advice would be to move to something like a C++ client from the [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) project which use the AMQP 1.0 protocol.